# save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object: How to save related models together?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a form and a formset. Formset contains a column foreign key to form. However my forms are not saving and `save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object` error is being thrown. How could I save both these data together?

here's my view:

```
def purchaseOrderView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = POFormSet(request.POST)
        form = POHeaderForm(request.POST)
        print("POSTED")
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            form.save()
            formset.save()
            messages.success(request,"VALID SUBMISSION")
            return render(request,'purchase_order.html',{'formset':formset, 'form':form})
        else:
            return render(request, 'purchase_order.html', {'formset': formset, 'form': form})
    else:
        formset = POFormSet()
        form = POHeaderForm()
        return render(request,'purchase_order.html',{'formset':formset, 'form':form})
```

here's my model structure:

```
class POHeaderModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, default=timezone.now)
    reference = models.CharField(validators=[alphanumeric], max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(SuppliersModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    note = models.CharField(validators=[alphanumeric], max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])

class POBodyModel(models.Model):
    PO = models.ForeignKey(POHeaderModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    item_number = models.CharField(validators=[alphanumeric], max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(validators=[alphanumeric], max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    rate = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    discount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10,blank=True, null=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, blank=False)
```

There are a lot of examples out there in various blogs and in here in questions using `with transaction.atomic():`. But none works or may be doesn't suit my scenario. Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass to formset the parent object, like this:

```
formset = POFormSet(request.POST,instance=POHeaderinstance)
```